# CTRL+C does not terminate aiohttp app in Python 3.6 script on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket.io, python-asyncio, aiohttp

A simple Python 3.6 script using `aiohttp` and `python-socketio` and running on Windows 10 outputs the following when started:

```
======== Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 ========
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

However, pressing CTRL+C does not terminate the script! I had to open Task Manager and kill each of the Python processes until killing one of them releases the `aiohttp` script back to the command prompt.

Any one experienced the same problem?

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio

sio = socketio.AsyncServer()
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print(sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

Comment: It seems that it has to do with asyncio and not with aiohttp specifically. See https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3004 and https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/407 . I haven't tested, but you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774980/why-cant-i-catch-sigint-when-asyncio-event-loop-is-running/24775107#24775107 as workaround